# SVG Opacity Transitions briefly go further than the CSS rules tell them to and appear to jump around

Tags: html, css, svg, css-transitions

I'm currently trying to get an SVG rect (in an svg embedded in html) to fade in when hovered over. I've noticed that the transition is extremely jumpy and at times goes outside of the range of values between the start and end opacities of the transition.

I am using Firefox. The rect's fill is pure red (#FF0000). By default, its opacity is 0.1. On hover, its opacity is 1. I took a video to keep track of the transition's progress over time. Below, I've noted the rect's `red` value at various points in the video. The rect is on a black background so I think the `red` value of the rect should be representative of the overall opacity of the rect. I am operating under the assumption that the expected behavior of the transition is to go from r=~25 (255 * 0.1) to r=255 (255 * 1). In actuality, the transition goes between r=23 and r=234. I assume this is a limitation of my video taking software. Anyway.

When hovering over the rect, the following happens:

1. The rect starts with a red value of 23
2. On hover, the rect immediately disappears, with a red value of 0
3. The rect fades to a red value of 26
4. The rect jumps to a red value of 100
5. The rect fades to a red value of 140
6. The rect jumps to a final red value of 234

And when the mouse moves away from the rect, the following happens:

7. The rect fades to a red value of 102
8. The rect jumps to a red value of 45
9. The rect fades to a red value of 10
10. The rect jumps to a final red value of 23

I am confused by two things. First, why does the opacity jump so much? I have very few other programs running so I doubt it's a lag issue. Second, why does the opacity go all the way down to `10` (as it does in step 9) instead of just stopping at 23? And how do I fix all of this?

My code is as follows:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Opacity transition test</title>
    <style>
        body > svg {
            background: black;
        }
        #the-rect {
            opacity: 0.1;
            transition: opacity 1s linear;
        }
        #the-rect:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="500" height="500">
        <rect id="the-rect" x="0" y="0" width="250" height="250" fill="#FF0000"/>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opacity doesn't animate very well in Firefox.

fill-opacity may be good enough for you though.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Opacity transition test</title>
    <style>
        body > svg {
            background: black;
        }
        #the-rect {
            fill-opacity: 0.1;
            transition: fill-opacity 1s linear;
        }
        #the-rect:hover {
            fill-opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="500" height="500">
        <rect id="the-rect" x="0" y="0" width="250" height="250" fill="#FF0000"/>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```